# How to show that B is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This is not a homework, this question came in my exam, and I did not know how to solve it.

"Let $A$ and $B$ be $3\times3$ matrices such that $AB = - BA$. Show that if $A$ is invertible, then $B$ is not invertible"

I tried starting with the expression $ AB = - BA$ and multiply $A$ by its inverse, but no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks good.  Your EDIT solution is correct.

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you for your feedback. Should I " Answer your Question" ?

Comment: You might just move everything under the edit to the answer and answer your own question.  That is definitely not a bad idea.

Comment: @TravisJ Just did, Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer:

$$\operatorname{det} (AB) = \operatorname{det} (-BA)\\
\operatorname{det} A \operatorname{det} B = (-1)^3 \operatorname{det} A \operatorname{det} B $$

dividing both equations by $\operatorname{det} A$ ($\operatorname{det} A$ is different than zero since $A$ is invertible)

$$\operatorname{det} B = (-1)^3 \operatorname{det} B$$

$\operatorname{det} B$ must be equal to zero, thus B is not invertible.

Comment: A few things to flesh out I would recommend.  "dividing both equations by det(A)."  This is only allowed if $det(A)\neq 0$, but that's fine because we were told $A$ is invertible (and therefore has nonzero determinant).  Also, at the end, you reached "det(B) must be equal to zero," but you could write the conclusion asked for by the problem which follows immediately from the previous statement that "$B$ is not invertible."  It also helps to remind the reader of the hypothesis by beginning with "Let $A,B$ be $3\times 3$ matrices with $AB=-BA$ and $A$ invertible."

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, I edited my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

We have $ABA^{-1}=-B$, meaning that $B$ and $-B$ have the same eigenvalues. It follows that the eigenvalue of $B$ is 0. Note that the size of the matrices is irrelevant here.